# How to excecute method after a delay in threading .timer?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I have a class that created a **threading .timer**.

```
  System.Threading.Timer timer;
  TimerCallback cb = new TimerCallback(ProcessTimerEvent);
    timer = new Timer(cb, reset, 1000, Convert.ToInt64(this.Interval.TotalSeconds));
}

private void ProcessTimerEvent(object obj)
{
    if (Tick != null)
        Tick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

I want dispose Timer inside of this and then timer work.

in my TickEvent i excecute a method but don't complate this.

```
 void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(value)
   MyFunction();
}
```

Timer must be taken to stop until MyFunction complete.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - if you dispose of the timer, then of course it won't work. Why don't you dispose of the timer *after* it's executed? It would help if you'd edit to clarify your question. (I realize English probably isn't your first language, but try really hard to make yourself clearer - it will be hard to help you otherwise.) You should also specify which kind of Timer you're using, and what sort of application you're writing.

Comment: @JonSkeet seems like he is using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, because only that timer has `Tick` event.. Other is still don't clear

Comment: @JonSkeet :I edit my question.. I use Threading.Timer ... i use timer.dispose(), but don't work for me.

Comment: "but don't work for me" is still *incredibly* vague. Did you read the page I linked to about how to ask good questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code.

TryEnter/Exit. No need to stop/restart the timer in that case; overlapping calls will not acquire the lock and return immediately.

```
object lockObject = new object();

private void ProcessTimerEvent(object state) 
 {
  if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
  {
   try
   {
   // Work here
   }
   finally
    {
   Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you timer holder class has name `MyTimer`. What you need is define method `Stop` which will dispose your `Threading.Timer` and turn off events raising.

```
public class MyTimer
{    
    System.Threading.Timer timer;
    bool enabled;
    TimeSpan interval;
    public event EventHandler Tick;

    public MyTimer(TimeSpan interval)
    {
        enabled = true;
        this.interval = interval;
        timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 1000, (int)interval.TotalSeconds);
    }

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        if (!enabled)
           return;

        if (Tick != null)
            Tick(this, EventArgs.Empty);          
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
        timer = null;
        enabled = false;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        enabled = true;
        timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 1000, (int)interval.TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

Then cast Tick event sender to your timer object and stop you timer while event is processed. After processing start timer again.

```
void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyTimer timer = (MyTimer)sender;
  timer.Stop(); // tick events will not be raised
  if(value)
     MyFunction();

  timer.Start(); // start timer again
}
```

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly you are genius, it also does not have Tick event

Comment: @ar.gorgin why not to switch to `System.Timers.Timer` instead?

Answer (score -1):

To stop timer you shoul [Timer.Change Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
public bool Change(int dueTime, int period)
```

> dueTime Specify Timeout.Infinite to prevent the timer from restarting.
>
> period Specify Timeout.Infinite to disable periodic signaling.

```
void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(value)
    {
        //this stop the timer because dueTime is -1
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        MyFunction();
        //this start the timer
        _timer.Change(Convert.ToInt64(this.Interval.TotalSeconds), Convert.ToInt64(this.Interval.TotalSeconds));
    }
}
```

> Timeout.Infinite is constant for -1

Comment: Thanks, but when i should use method Change()? i want stop timer befor of MyFunction().

Comment: `_timer.Change(1, Timeout.Infinite);` this will not stop timer - it will invoke callback once more in one millisecond. Then timer will be again set to one more invocation. Etc

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly it will run once, callback will be executed, and timer will be changed to run once more.

Comment: ar.gorgin i changed the code to stop timer in before MyFunction

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly and this also will not work, because `TimerCallback` has signature `void (object)`

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly and this also will not compile :)